# Find the solution for Cauchy problem using transformation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm learning differential equations for the first semester and I'm not sure how to even begin with the following problem:

Find the solution for Cauchy problem using transformation:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(1-t^2)x''-tx'+n^2x=0 & n \in \mathbb{Z}\\  
y(0)=1 & y'(0)=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Could you please help me?

Comment: One start could be to set $u(s)=x(\sin(s))$, compute derivatives and insert. Then check if a sufficient simplification was achieved. Is there a connection to the Chebyshev/Tschebyschef polynomials?

Comment: @LutzLehmann how should I know that I am supposed to put u(s)=x(sin(s))?

Comment: If you do a parameter transformation $u(s)=x(a(s))$, its second derivative starts with $a'(s)^2x''(a(s))+...$. Now equate $1-t^2=1-a(s)^2$ with $a'(s)^2$ to end up with the circle equation $1=a'(s)^2+a(s)^2$, harmonic oscillator $a''(s)+a(s)=0$ and trigonometric functions as possible solutions. But it may turn out to just transform one difficult equation into the next.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this belongs to an ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0220.pdf

Let $s=\int\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\sin^{-1}t$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{dx}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dx}{ds}\right)+\dfrac{t}{(1-t^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{d}{ds}\left(\dfrac{dx}{ds}\right)\dfrac{ds}{dt}+\dfrac{t}{(1-t^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{d^2x}{ds^2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}+\dfrac{t}{(1-t^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}=\dfrac{1}{1-t^2}\dfrac{d^2x}{ds^2}+\dfrac{t}{(1-t^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}$

$\therefore(1-t^2)\left(\dfrac{1}{1-t^2}\dfrac{d^2x}{ds^2}+\dfrac{t}{(1-t^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}\right)-\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}+n^2x=0$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{ds^2}+\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}-\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{dx}{ds}+n^2x=0$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{ds^2}+n^2x=0$

$x=C_1\sin ns+C_2\cos ns$

$x=C_1\sin(n\sin^{-1}t)+C_2\cos(n\sin^{-1}t)$

$x(0)=1$ :

$C_2=1$

$\therefore x=C_1\sin(n\sin^{-1}t)+\cos(n\sin^{-1}t)$

$x'=\dfrac{C_1n\cos(n\sin^{-1}t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}-\dfrac{n\sin(n\sin^{-1}t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

$x'(0)=0$ :

$C_1n=0$

$C_1=0$

$\therefore x=\cos(n\sin^{-1}t)$

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I would know it without this website?